Draw vertical line between points on twinned axes
This question answers how to draw a vertical line between two points on the same axis: Matplotlib how to draw vertical line between two Y points. But what if we have two separate sets of points each on a different twinned axis?
Given the plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

num_points = 100

# Generate x-values 
x_values = np.arange(num_points)

# Create a decreasing linear function
slope = -0.1
intercept = 5
y_values = slope * x_values + intercept

# Add random noise 
noise_scale = 0.5
y_values += np.random.normal(0, noise_scale, num_points)

# Create the numpy arrays
random_points = np.column_stack((x_values, y_values))
random_numbers = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, num_points)

# Creat DF
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x_values, 'y0': y_values, 'y1': random_numbers})

# Plot the points
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y0', c='b', marker='o', label='y0')
ax.legend().set_visible(False)
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.scatter(df['x'], df['y1'], color='darkorange', marker='o', label='y1')
ax1.legend().set_visible(False)
plt.show()

How would I put a vertical line between each y value on the same x?

One approach is this use ax.transData.transform and then transform these display coordinates back to data coordinates using fig.transFigure.inverted().transform in the following manner:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

num_points = 100
x_values = np.arange(num_points)
slope = -0.1
intercept = 5
y_values = slope * x_values + intercept
noise_scale = 0.5
y_values += np.random.normal(0, noise_scale, num_points)
random_numbers = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, num_points)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x_values, 'y0': y_values, 'y1': random_numbers})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y0', c='b', marker='o', label='y0', ax=ax)
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.scatter(df['x'], df['y1'], color='darkorange', marker='o', label='y1')

ylim0 = ax.get_ylim()
ylim1 = ax1.get_ylim()

for x, y0, y1 in zip(df['x'], df['y0'], df['y1']):
    y1_in_ax_coords = (y1 - ylim1[0]) / (ylim1[1] - ylim1[0])
    y1_in_ax_data = ylim0[0] + y1_in_ax_coords * (ylim0[1] - ylim0[0])
    ax.plot([x, x], [y0, y1_in_ax_data], color='grey', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()


which gives you


These lines seem inconsistent and don't quite connect the points. Do you know why that is?

@DrakeMurdoch My apologies. Fixed it and updated the code.
